# Load a css class on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div and when i hover that div i want to call another css class. I have used some ways i've found but i cannot get it to work.

**html code**

```
     <div className="trait_box polaroid">
           <div className="trait_description_div">
                <span className="trait_description">Honesty</span>
           </div>

           <div className="trait_img_div">
                <img src={Honesty} className="trait_img"/>
           </div>

           <div className="block__body">
                <h3>Card Title</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
```

SO when i hover `trait_box` class i want to load `block__body` class. How can i do it?

I've tried the following way but did not work and it showed some errors in red lines.

```
.trait_box {

    width: 220px;
    height: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover .block__body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:#2980b9;
    color:#fff;
    height:100%;
    transition: top .5s;

    h3 { color: #fff; }
}

}
```

Comment: Class attribute is written as `<div class="className">`. Where do you need to use `class` attribute as `className` ??

Comment: in reactjs you have to give it as className

Comment: Thanks, i was completely unaware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stylesheet code looks like SCSS that will need to be compiled to CSS to have the effect you want. Here is an example below using plain HTML and CSS and a placeholder image.

Note: I am totally unfamiliar with React. From what I gather, `className` will be rendered as the `class` attribute, and the `img` source `{Honesty}` will be converted to a string.

```css
.trait_box {
    width: 220px;
    height: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trait_box:hover .block__body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:#2980b9;
    color:#fff;
    height:100%;
    transition: top .5s;
}

.trait_box:hover .block__body h3 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="trait_box polaroid">
           <div class="trait_description_div">
                <span className="trait_description">Honesty</span>
           </div>

           <div class="trait_img_div">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" className="trait_img"/>
           </div>

           <div class="block__body">
                <h3>Card Title</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by *"loading"* the class. Typically that means you want the class to be added to the element. What I *think* you mean is you want to select `.block__body` when `.trait_box` is hovered. I also assume you're using SCSS because of the nested styles. That's an important piece of information to give readers. I will give you the answer in vanilla CSS as the problem very well might be you are **not** using SCSS.

```css
    .trait_box {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: navy;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .block__body {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background: skyblue;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transition: background-color 300ms ease;
    }
    .trait_box:hover .block__body {
      background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="trait_box">
  <div class="block__body"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave to handle hover in pure react way

```
   <div className={divClassName} 
        onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler} 
        onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}>
       <div className="trait_description_div">
            <span className="trait_description">Honesty</span>
       </div>

       <div className="trait_img_div">
            <img src={Honesty} className="trait_img"/>
       </div>

       <div className="block__body">
            <h3>Card Title</h3>
       </div>
   </div>


divClassName="trait_box polaroid";//or save it in a state

onMouseEnterHandler = () ={
    divClassName = divClassName +" block__body"//use setState if its in state
}
onMouseLeaveHandler = () ={
    divClassName = "trait_box polaroid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your code somewhat, this is what it would look like.

What I understand is, you want to show captions when your parent div is `hovered`.
That is simply possible. You don't need to add a new `class` you just need to add some `CSS properties`.

```css
.trait_box {
  position: relative;
  /* because, absolute needs a relative parent */
  width: 220px;
  height: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.trait_box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* just to make the demo image fix properly in your given width */
  height: auto;
}

.trait_box:hover .block__body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* if you want to cover full parent width */
  background: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  transition: top .5s;
}

h3 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="trait_box polaroid">
  <div class="trait_description_div">
    <span class="trait_description">Honesty</span>
  </div>

  <div class="trait_img_div">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-274-234-7.jpg" class="trait_img" />
  </div>

  <div class="block__body">
    <h3>Card Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use jQuery or Javascript in the following way:

```
$('.myDiv').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery as below

```
$(".trait_box").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("block__body");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("block__body");
  }
);
```

or like this

```
$(".trait_box").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("block__body");
 });
```